# display popup while creating deferred components

Tags: apache-flex

I have an app that has a ViewStack.  The stack has about 15 or so full-screen panels, each of which has a lot going on.  So the creation of each panel's children is deferred (using creationPolicy) until they are needed.  I want to display something as a modal popup (please wait...) before the creation for a panel begins, like so:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.root, true);

LayoutManager.getInstance().usePhasedInstantiation = false; 
theStack.thePanel.createComponentsFromDescriptors(true);
LayoutManager.getInstance().usePhasedInstantiation = true;

PopUpManager.removePopUp(instance);
```

but of course what seems to happen is that nothing is displayed, the creation takes place,
lasting a few seconds, then the popup quickly appears and disappears.

How can I force the popup to display after addPopUp before proceeding?

Comment: I'm curious: what is going on in that panel that it would take seconds to create? Even creating a few thousand components wouldn't take that much time. Are you doing some heavy calculations?

Comment: Well that's the mystery, isn't it?  We ave a lot of custom mx components with several properties each.  On a browser it's no big deal, but in a Flex Mobile app running on iPad 2 it's noticeable.

Comment: mx components aren't particularly lightweight to start with. You should only use Spark components in a mobile application and even then you should avoid some of those (like DataGrid). But I guess you already knew that. As for your question: I think you should listen for the creation event of the popup; _then_ start initializing the panel and listen for its creation event; then remove the popup.